# Installing open cv and python to run together

Tags: opencv

I have already installed Open CV 2.4.0 beta in (D:/BACKUP/install/opencv) and installed python 2.7.2, scipy  and numpy fpr 2.7 in (D:/BACKUP/install/python). Now I want to know what should I do to make it work fine. Help me with clear and step by step guide to set up my environmental variables and other settings that i should make so that i can start using it.

Answer (score 1):

What about a small slice a googling/reading the doc ?

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide

http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/setup-opencv-for-python/

Answer (score 0):

I find this compilation of pre-compiled binaries extremely useful.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Every time i have problems installing anything with pip, these always seem to do the trick.